# bootstrap modal close event removes some portion of the document body

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have two `bootstrap modal` and I use one at a time. The **first modal** works fine, but the **second modal** has an effect to document body.

When opened **second modal** then close it via close button, upon closing the **second modal** there is an effect which removes some portion on the right side of the document.

I'm stuck with this. I'll appreciate any help. thanks!

[image: highlighted red border box]

Comment: the red bordered indicates the problem when I close the modal, it becomes a free space ,. Before opening the 2nd modal , the table and my nav bar are fully indented to the right side of the page.

Comment: Could you please share the code or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)